# Сохранение нескольких дат в preferences

Tags: java, android

Как вывести данные даты Nabor и сохранить? Без preferences выводятся. В итоге должно получиться 5-8 дат с разным интервалом. И мне нужно их сохранить.

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etText;
    Button btnSave, btnLoad;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    EditText Nabor;

    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    final String SAVED_TEXT2 = "date timer";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView Vilup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextdata3);
        long date1 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (2 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateV = sdf.format(date1);
        Vilup.setText(dateV);

        TextView Period1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate2);
        long date2 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (5 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy");
        String dateX = p.format(date2);
        Period1.setText(dateX);

        Nabor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        long date3 = System.currentTimeMillis()+ (5 * 86400000);
        SimpleDateFormat N = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
        String dateY = N.format(date3);
        Nabor.setText(dateY);






        etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etText);
      //  etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextDate2);

        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLoad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(this);

        loadText();

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnSave:
                saveText();
                break;
            case R.id.btnLoad:
                loadText();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


    }

    private void loadText() {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
        etText.setText(savedText);
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String savedText2 = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT2, "");
Nabor.setText(savedText2);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }



    private void saveText() {

        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, etText.getText().toString());
        ed.commit();
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefer", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor eds = sPref.edit();
        eds.putString(SAVED_TEXT2, Nabor.getText().toString());
        eds.commit();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        saveText();
    }


} ```
````

Comment: ну, по коду вижу, что даты вы сохраняете в SAVED_TEXT2 в виде текста. Должно работать, или вы чего-то другого хотите?

Comment: Да он сохраняется но не выводится из даты. Если в ручную ввожу да выводиться.

Comment: что значит "не выводиться из даты"? Приведите пример

Comment: К чему эти сложности с разными префами? MyPref, MyPrefer? Можно в один писать

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста. Понимаю что раздуто выходит. Но не могу найти пример чтобы понять. У меня дата должна выводится в elitText. 1- текущая 2 - +дни, 3+ дни и т.д. Потом все данные сохраняются и их можно вернуть. Ручной ввод не подходит так как все идет от текущей даты.